Endpoint not displayed with same request mapping but different params
I use spring boot
Theses 2 endpoints is in controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/deposits")

@GetMapping(params = "idDepositSignal")
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> adviseDeposit(@RequestParam List<Long> idDepositSignal) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(depositService.adviceDeposit(idDepositSignal), HttpStatus.OK);
}


@GetMapping(params = "idDepositDuplicate")
public ResponseEntity<Deposit> duplicateDeposit(@RequestParam Long idDepositDuplicate) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(depositService.duplicateDeposit(idDepositDuplicate), HttpStatus.OK);
}

In another controller with
@RequestMapping(value = "/deposits")


@GetMapping("/{depositId}")
public ResponseEntity<DepositInfo> getDepositInfo(@PathVariable Long depositId) {

    return new ResponseEntity<>(depositService.getDeposit(depositId), HttpStatus.OK);
}

When i go in swagger ui, my first and second endpoint is not displayed, but i can call it
I tried to delete one of the two first endpoint... but the other is not displayed.
Seem a bug
swagger display both endpoint in the same space, take one of the both description and display all parameter of the two function....
very very bad...

Here is the solution shown below
As both of your first two endpoints (/deposits) use the same path with different query parameters, Swagger is unable to differentiate them correctly.
1 ) Use Explicit @Operation Annotations (1st way for solution)
@RequestMapping(value = "/deposits")
@RestController
public class DepositController {

    @GetMapping(params = "idDepositSignal")
    @Operation(
        summary = "Advise Deposit",
        description = "Advise a deposit based on a list of deposit signal IDs",
        operationId = "adviseDeposit"
    )
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> adviseDeposit(@RequestParam List<Long> idDepositSignal) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(depositService.adviceDeposit(idDepositSignal), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping(params = "idDepositDuplicate")
    @Operation(
        summary = "Duplicate Deposit",
        description = "Duplicate a deposit based on the given deposit ID",
        operationId = "duplicateDeposit"
    )
    public ResponseEntity<Deposit> duplicateDeposit(@RequestParam Long idDepositDuplicate) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(depositService.duplicateDeposit(idDepositDuplicate), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

2 ) Separate Endpoints into Different Paths (2nd way for solution)
@RequestMapping(value = "/deposits")
@RestController
public class DepositController {

    @GetMapping("/advise")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> adviseDeposit(@RequestParam List<Long> idDepositSignal) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(depositService.adviceDeposit(idDepositSignal), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/duplicate")
    public ResponseEntity<Deposit> duplicateDeposit(@RequestParam Long idDepositDuplicate) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(depositService.duplicateDeposit(idDepositDuplicate), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

